# How to detect access denied/unauthorized activity logs in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-diagnostics

My objective is to detect actions performed by users that resulted in an access denied or unauthorized error using activity logs.

To detect error I use the field "resultType" field. When it is "Failure", I know that this is an error record. I want to go one step further and filter those which are "access denied" or "unauthorized" error records.

I have considered following fields so far as potential candidates for the same, however haven't found any relevant information in them.

- resultDescription
- properties.statusCode

Following is the sample schema of the activity log we get on our end. The schema is such because we stream our activity log to a storage account(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log-schema#schema-from-storage-account-and-event-hubs)

> When streaming the Azure Activity log to a storage account or event hub, the data >?>follows the resource log schema.

```
{
    "callerIpAddress" : "0.0.0.0",
    "resourceGroup" : "group",
    "resourceId" : "dummy",
    "level" : "Information",
    "production" : false,
    "operationName" : "MICROSOFT.WEB/DUMMY",
    "ingestTime" : "time",
    "resultSignature" : "Succeeded.OK",
    "accountId" : "dummyId",
    "identity" : {
      "authorization" : {
        "evidence" : {
          "roleAssignmentScope" : "group",
          "role" : "dummy",
          "roleDefinitionId" : "dummy",
          "roleAssignmentId" : "dummy",
          "principalId" : "dummy",
          "principalType" : "dummy"
        },
        "scope" : "dummy",
        "action" : "dummy"
      },
      "claims" : {
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" : "dummy",
        "appid" : "dummy",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" : "dummy"
      }
    },
    "customerID" : "dummy",
    "correlationId" : "dummy",
    "time" : "dummy",
    "category" : "dummy",
    "resultType" : "Failure",
    "resultDescription": "dummy",
    "durationMs" : "dummy",
    "properties" : {
      "eventCategory" : "Administrative",
      "statusCode" : "OK"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You cannot get access denied or authorization unsuccessful logs in Activity Logs in Azure Portal.

I created one User with Reader role on Azure subscription and tried creating a Container in the Storage account and got authorization error like below:-

[image]

***I tried to get the logs for the same activity in Activity logs but I did not get any logs related to the same, Refer below:-***

[image]

I tried to select Audit logs with **testreader** but got access denied error like below:-

[image]

Tried checking the same logs in the Activity log and did not find any relevant log on the same, refer below:-

[image]

I tried checking Audit logs in Azure AD but it did not give access denied or authorization errors, Instead it only gave creation of authorization and authentication for users and apps, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]